# Get minimum value from columnconcat from three tables + lpad inside. MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working in SQL Server Managment Studio 2014.

In the project I am working on I have three tables, each containing 2 columns, one datetime with the exact date (but on time is contained) and the other one - smallint containing time (8:55 is 855 value, while for example 14:45 is 1445).

What I want to do is to get minimum value which is merged from both of those columns from all of those three tables.

What I have figure out by myself until now is:

1. Use `lpad("U_StartTime", 0, '4')` to fill values like 855 into 0855 (for exact comparison). However `lpad` is not recognized at my studio.

   > `lpad` is not recognized built in function
2. Then I can merge both columns like this:

   ```
   SELECT concat("U_StartDate", ' ', "U_StartTime") FROM "TABLE1".
   ```

   This is ok until I try make it with `lpad`.
3. Then I may take all values to consider like this:

   ```
   SELECT concat("U_StartDate", ' ', "U_StartTime") FROM "TABLE1"
   UNION
   SELECT concat("U_StartDate", ' ', "U_StartTime") FROM "TABLE2"
   ...
   ```
4. And I can take `MIN(column)` but I do not know how to get `MIN` from the whole `UNION SELECT` (of those three tables).

Thank you in advance for any advices on my current sql problems.

edit - image for NikHil:
[image]

EDIT:
I have changed the way a bit. Now I am modifying datetime object rather than working on string comparison. As an example for someone I paste part of the code:

```
select DATEADD(minute, "U_StartTime"%100, DATEADD(hour, "U_StartTime"/100, "U_StartDate")) from "TABLE1"
```

rather than

```
select MIN(concat("U_StartDate", ' ', RIGHT('0000' + "U_StartTime", '4'))) from "TABLE1"
```

Comment: Please explain with examples ,rather than words and show some input and expected output

Comment: also tag either sql/mysql unless you want your query to run in both

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try this

`select data from
(
select concat("U_StartDate", ' ', "U_StartTime")as 'data' from "TABLE1"
UNION
select concat("U_StartDate", ' ', "U_StartTime")as 'data' from "TABLE2"
...
)
where data is not null
order by data asc
LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is nice way, but the data outside of the external ( ) is not recognized column.

Comment: But we can get minimum row value from the above query

Comment: I have uploaded the post with the image showing the problem with your suggestion. I mean this is great hint, but there should be just syntactic error in my code or the proposed answered. 
In edit I also mentioned that I changed way going on string, and I am modifying datetime column I have.
Thanks NikHil for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RIGHT` instead of `lpad`

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + '855', 4) -- 0855
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + '1445', 4) -- 1445
```

Query looks like

```
SELECT MIN(RIGHT('0000' + YourColumn, 4) * 1)
FROM
    Tbl
```